# Convert coordinate to tile row and tile column in Google Maps when using custom projection

Tags: google-maps, wmts

I'm trying to get Google Maps (javascript SDK) to use a different tile server that serves tiles as EPSG:3006. I'm using Proj4js to convert the coordinates.

So far I have this code:

```
 proj4.defs("EPSG:3006", "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
 var googleProj = proj4("EPSG:4326")
 var lantmaterietProj = proj4("EPSG:3006")
 var projectionTransform = proj4(googleProj, lantmaterietProj)

 var lantmaterietMapType;
 function initLantmateriet() {
   lantmaterietMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
     getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
       return "https://api.lantmateriet.se/open/topowebb-ccby/v1/wmts/token/secret-token/1.0.0/topowebb/default/3006/" + zoom + "/" + coord.y + "/" + coord.x + ".png";
     },
     tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
     minZoom: 0,
     maxZoom: 9,
     name: 'Lantmateriet'
   });

   lantmaterietMapType.projection = {
     fromLatLngToPoint: function(latLng) {
       var newPoint = projectionTransform.forward([latLng.lng(), latLng.lat()]);
       return new google.maps.Point(newPoint[0], newPoint[1]);
     },
     fromPointToLatLng: function(point, noWrap) {
       var newPoint = projectionTransform.inverse([point.x, point.y]);
       return new google.maps.LatLng(newPoint[0], newPoint[1]);
     }
   };
 }
```

The `coord.x` and `coord.y` in the `getTileUrl` function cannot be put in the url like that. I'm not sure how to calculate the correct tile row and tile column though.

Any ideas on how to calculate the correct tile row and column here?

Comment: What do you mean by "The coord.x and coord.y in the getTileUrl function cannot be put in the url like that." This is exactly how you are supposed to load custom tile sets.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I'm not sure... The coord.x and .y are very large, like 256000 but the tileRow/Col should be around 800. So something is definitely weird here though I'm not really sure what.

Comment: It is hard to understand what is going on because you haven't posted the code that returns coord.x and coord.y. I suspect you will also have difficulties overlaying 3306 in Google Maps, as 3306 is Transverse Mercator, so the tiles will not line up with Google's Web Mercator (3857). In the [example in Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image), you will see the the mapTypeID is set to moon, rather than street, satellite, etc, and the lat/lon is set to 0,0.

Comment: There is then a normalized image function, causing the overlay tiles to line up correctly in x and y direction.

Comment: Hi, have you manage to solve this? I have the same issue. Here is my WMTS xml http://gis.arso.gov.si/arcgis/rest/services/Lidar_hillshade/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: @MaticDiba I have not.